# How must you spin the ball to make it alternate between 2 positions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, elasticity

[image]

Assume any parameters you may need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to consider also the frictional force. What is SHM?

Comment: SHM=Simple Harmonic Motion

Comment: As mentioned in our [FAQ#questions], "vanilla" homework questions are not appropriate for this site. Nic has given you some nice hints so perhaps those will help you; otherwise, if you narrow this question down to the physical principle that is giving you trouble, it could be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

As this looks a lot like a homework question I'll give some brief hints.

1. Consider which way the ball must be spinning.
2. Will the magnitude of the horizontal velocity $v$ change?
3. Whats the relationship between rotational velocity and linear velocity for a point on the circumference?

Comment: Very "tricky"! +1